# How do I create a predicate that matches a range of integers in prolog?

Tags: prolog

I'm honestly not sure if this is the correct approach to querying for a range of values in prolog or if I'm barking up the wrong tree.

```
earningstatus(between(1, 12999), low).
earningstatus(0, unemployed).
```

The unemployed rule works correctly, but the 'low' rule does not. What is the correct way to write this predicate so that it returns low for a range of values?

(I am using SWI-Prolog.)

Comment: `earningstatus(V, low) :- between(1,12999,V).` or `..., V >= 1, ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turning [the comment by false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26819388/how-do-i-create-a-predicate-that-matches-a-range-of-integers-in-prolog#comment42208478_26819388) into a (CW) answer.

> ```
>  earningstatus(V, low) :- between(1,12999,V).
> ```